# @ManagedBean annotation doesnt work, but @Named works

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jsf-2, cdi

I had some troubles.
Class with @Named works:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

@Autowired
UserBo userBo;

public void setUserBo(UserBo userBo) {
    this.userBo = userBo;
}

public String printMsgFromSpring() {
    return userBo.getMessage();
}

}
```

but this is doesnt work and generates error:

*javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.mkyong.UserBean.printMsgFromSpring(UserBean.java:24)*

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

@Autowired
UserBo userBo;

public void setUserBo(UserBo userBo) {
  this.userBo = userBo;
}

public String printMsgFromSpring() {
  return userBo.getMessage();
}

}
```

xhtml page:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>

    <h1>JSF 2.0 + Spring Example</h1>

    #{userBean.printMsgFromSpring()}


</h:body>
```

faces-config.xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

    </faces-config>
```

Service class:

```
@Named
public class UserBoImpl implements UserBo{

  public String getMessage() {
        return "JSF 2 + Spring Integration";

  }

}
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

      <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
       </listener-class>
   </listener>

   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />
     </beans>
```

Comment: Please post your spring context.

Comment: Thx, i add applicationContext.xml to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF won't process the `@Autowired`. You should replace that with `@ManagedProperty` as in the following example:

```
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userBoSpringName}")
    UserBo userBo;
```

Here `userBoSpringName` should correspond to the name of the bean in your spring context file.
This option is usable in a JSF managed bean only.

As of JSF 2.2, you can also use `@Inject` in a JSF managed bean to perform resource injections

Comment: Big thx, i tryed to use Inject annotation, but didnt know what it works only in JSF 2.2.
Also i tryed to use Component annotation  instead of ManagedBean , and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

You've made some assumptions that I believe are wrong. Spring can read `@Named` and `Inject` annotations, but I doubt your JSF DI container can read `Autowired` annotations. In this case

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

    @Autowired
    UserBo userBo;

    public void setUserBo(UserBo userBo) {
        this.userBo = userBo;
    }

    public String printMsgFromSpring() {
        return userBo.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I believe Spring is creating a `UserBean` instance (because of `@Named`) and injecting a `UserBo` bean (that also comes from a `@Named` class). Spring ignores `SessionScoped`.

In this case, however,

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {
    @Autowired
    UserBo userBo;

    public void setUserBo(UserBo userBo) {
      this.userBo = userBo;
    }

    public String printMsgFromSpring() {
      return userBo.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I believe your JSF container is creating this bean, but has no idea what `@Autowired` is so doesn't process it, it ignores it.

My answer would be more clear if you showed us your Spring context configuration and where you expect the above beans to come from.

Comment: JSF doesn't process Spring annotations, so this approach will fail. Usually, you configure Spring to handle JSF managed beans or stop using Spring and move to CDI to solve this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yup, Spring knows and processes `@Named` as if it was `@Component`. It does nothing with `@SessionScoped`. On the other hand, JSF doesn't know `@Autowired` so that field remains `null`.